# Non-Destructive Type Assertions in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I am looking for a good way of constraining a literal value in TypeScript to certain type without loosing inferred type information.

Let's consider a type `Named` that is guaranteed to have a name.

```js
type Named = {
  name: string
};
```

Using a type annotation creates an error for the extra field `born` in the literal used to define the const `cat1`.

```js
const cat1: Named = {
  name: 'Findus',
  born: 1984,  // this is an error
};
const name1 = cat1.name;
const born1 = cat1.born;  // this is an error
```

By using a typecast I can define the const `cat2` but it looses type information for the field `born` which creates a problem while trying to access that field later on.

```js
const cat2 = {
  name: 'Findus',
  born: 1984,
} as Named;
const name2 = cat2.name;
const born2 = cat2.born;  // this is an error
```

One way to solve the problem is to use an IIFE to type check the literal while defining the const `cat3`.

```js
const cat3 = (<C extends Named>(c: C) => c)({
  name: 'Findus',
  born: 1984,
});
const name3 = cat3.name;
const born3 = cat3.born;
```

Is this the intended way of doing the constraining, or are there better alternative ways of writing compatible code?

Comment: Yeah, using a function is the way to both constrain and infer the type. There is no other syntax for this.

Comment: why not remove the type annotation?

Comment: Because then the cat would no longer be guaranteed to have a name since you could make a typo while defining the literal value. Things might later break when someone imports the cat from another package since the cat would not match the given type definition.

Comment: There seems to be an open issue about this but the page is not accessible at the moment for some reason https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7481

Answer (score 0):

Simply say that your type is a record with one required parameter **name**

```
interface Named extends Record<string, any> {
    name: string
}
```

Or you can use something like this

```
type Named<T> = T & {
    name: string
}


const a: Named<{ surname: string } > = {
    name: 'hello',
    surname: 'world'
};
```

Comment: The issue here is, the first one will add an index signature to `Named`, so `cat1.foofoo` would compile as well. With the second one, you will have to repeat every property in type.

Comment: Yeah, there is not other way than extends or such tricks I mentioned